# How to assign output from SOLVE function in PROC FCMP (SAS) to global variable/table?

Tags: sas, fcmp

I'm trying to use PROC FCMP with the function SOLVE to solve non-linear equations and insert solutions into the table automatically.
For instance

```
proc fcmp;
      /* define the function */
   function inversesqrt(x);
      return(1/sqrt(x));
   endsub;

   y = 20;
   x = solve("inversesqrt", {.}, y, .);
   put x;
run;
```

After running above code **x** will be shown in results but i cannot utilize it in further code. 
I tried to save **x** as macro variable or as table but nothing works for me.
Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second `fcmp` function to return the solve.

```
options cmplib=work.funcs;

proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.sandbox;
      /* define the function */
   function InverseSqrt(x);
      return(1/sqrt(x));
   endsub;

   function SolveInverseSqrt(arg);
     return (solve('InverseSqrt', {.}, arg, .));
   endsub;
run;

%let x = %sysfunc(SolveInverseSqrt(20));
%put &=x;
```